# Case activities are not shown in activity tab but appear in the filter

Tags: civicase, activities, issues

In the Activity tab for a contact, case activities are not shown. I would rather they were, but I can live without that.

But in the filter for including and excluding activity types from the view, the case activities appear. Surely this is a bug. Since case activities are not shown in the tab, it makes no sense to filter by them.

In an organisation with a large amount of case activity types this makes the filter pretty much unusable because the list is so long and largely irrelevant.

I found the offending line of code, it is line 40 in CRM/Activity/Form/ActivityFilter.php

`$activityOptions = CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::activityType(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 'label', TRUE);`

It seems to be the first parameter being set to TRUE that makes it include case activites.

Should I file a bug, what do you think?

Comment: Agree it should be consistent

Answer (score 3):

> In the Activity tab for a contact, case activities are not shown. I would rather they were...

Me too! And After a lengthy process I've had this [PR 1630](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16360) merged into core, should be released in 5.24 I think.

It adds an option (**Administer » CiviCase » CiviCase Settings**) that, if checked, will include case activities in the activities tab (and other activities listings that they were previously hidden from).

I felt that not having these exposed in the normal way led to some really strange situations - like if a case activity is assigned to me, I would not be able to see it from my record at all. You may want to [read my rationale](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16360#issuecomment-582904647) for why this option made sense.